60s YA story about a boy aiding a phoenix in battling griffons
I recall reading a Young Adult library book (its possible it was a short story from an anthology) in the late 60s early 70s. (Being a library book the story could have been 5-10 years older.)
There was one scene I recall of the story. A young boy (10-12?) was wandering/exploring (possibly a mountainous area.) near his home.
He slips when he finds a large nest and falls down the slope and lands in or near the nest. Turns out it is a phoenix nest, and the phoenix startled by his arrival either leaps into the air, or was flying nearby. Seeing the boy in/near the nest the phoenix dives bombs to attack the boy. But at the last moment realizes the boy is not a threat (either due to his cries, or attempts to help the eggs/chicks in the nest, or attempts to repair any damage he caused by landing in the nest) and instead lands beside the boy.
Turns out phoenix can talk and the boy and phoenix start talking and later the boy aids the phoenix is his battle with its archrival griffons.
I remember a few years later watching Peter Falk's "Griffin and Phoenix" (1976) TV movie thinking it was the story I had read, but being surprised it was not (but still enjoyed the movie) So I know it was probably around 1970 when I read the book.

Except for the griffons, this reminds me of David and the Phoenix.

@PatWagnerDenver That seems a good call to me. David and the Phoenix not only has gryffens, but also gryffins, and the fearsome gryffons.

It does sound like David and the Phoenix, but David doesn't fall into the nest. When David first sees the Phoenix he is spying on it from behind a bush, and the Phoenix is reading a book of Latin grammar.

Now I have to go back and read it again. Was a childhood fave, which means it has been a few decades. I enjoyed the Phoenix taking David on a tour of classical mythology.

David and the Phoenix sure sounds like it is a possibility, But I have a vivid recall that the meeting between them was the Phoenix divebombed to attack the MC before stopping when he realized MC was not a threat. I checked the Wikipedia summary, and Many more creatures are introduced in the story. (Witch, Leprechaun, Hag, Faun, etc.) none of which I recall, But it had been 50 years since I read it.

I see it was included in the Weekly Reader. (US children's magazine distributed in MANY schools in English classes for elementary students) and I might have read a shortened version of it in there?
